# Consistency level: QUORUM or QUOROM spring-data-cassandra?

Tags: consistency, spring-data-cassandra

In `org.springframework.data:spring-cql`,

```
package org.springframework.cassandra.core;

/**
 * Generic Consistency Levels associated with Cassandra.
 * 
 * @author David Webb
 */
public enum ConsistencyLevel {

    ANY, ONE, TWO, THREE, QUOROM, LOCAL_QUOROM, EACH_QUOROM, ALL, LOCAL_ONE, SERIAL, LOCAL_SERIAL

}
```

Is 'QUOROM' a typo or Spring-data intentionally writes like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are implying by this...

> Is 'QUOROM' a typo or Spring-data intentionally writes like that?

But, perhaps you should take a look at...

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/54

Clearly, this was a typo by the original authors of the project.  More recently, SD Cassandra has been pulled in as a **Pivotal** owned and maintained project.

While we do plan to merge this PR (soon, probably for the `1.5.M1 (Ingalls)` release), it is also an interface breaking change so requires careful attention, which has been appropriately and soundly [done](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pull/54/files) by [atoumle](https://github.com/atoulme).

At any rate, we always welcome community contributions and feedback, so you are welcome to open a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20DATACASS) or submit a [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/pulls) if you feel something is not correct, whether that be source code, documentation or examples.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was a typo, but I didn't find a JIRA and that pull request. Because that enum is almost same as the one in cassandra java driver, I am not sure why spring-data cassandra defines its own class.

Comment: No worries, both @mp911de and I are still figuring out the reasoning for a lot of things as well.  Our goal is to simplify, reduce and improve upon the SDC codebase.  Naturally, overtime, a codebase collects a bit of cruft and the reasoning behind things is not always clear.  Cheers.